# RabbitMQ: routing on multiple criteria but hitting only one consumer

Tags: message-queue, rabbitmq, zeromq

How can we distribute work via RabbitMQ such that worker pools can subscribe to work messages based on differing (but frequently overlapping) criteria from each other but such that when a message is routed that matches to multiple worker pools, only one worker will pick up the job?

Simplified example:

- We have host1 and host2.
- Host1 handles jobs of classA and classB; host2 handles jobs of classB and classC.
- If we route a job of
  classA, only host1 will pick it up; if we route a job of classB,
  either host1 or host2 will pick it up (based on their current load /
  first available) but never both.

It would seem that we need to use a topic exchange, as our routing criteria is complex and using wildcards gives us the type of flexible matching we want.

However:

1. If we use the same name for the worker pool queue (say “worker-jobs”) we get the desired work splitting out to arbitrary matching workers, but every worker subscribing to the named queue seems to infect the other workers with each other’s routing criteria as they bind it. I.e. the binding of the routing key seems to be at the central queue name level not on a connection-to-queue basis.
2. If we use different queue names for each worker pool connection (say “poolA-jobs” and “poolB-jobs”) to the same exchange then we get the desired behavior with the different routing criteria maintained between pools but a job coming in that can match to both poolA and poolB gets routed to both of them (albeit only to one worker in each).

Notes:

1. I’ve spared you the details of why but suffice to say we have an existing multi-petabyte distributed search application that needs response times < 50ms. We already achieve this with our own custom routing hub but we’d like to replace this with RabbitMQ as its performance is attractive (as is retiring homemade code that overlaps with general purpose community projects) if we can get the sophisticated routing we need.
2. We use Python
3. Disco isn’t viable for many reasons, too numerous to go into.
4. It doesn’t have to be RabbitMQ but the performance needs to be as good. ØMQ looks very interesting and like it might provide both the flexibility and the performance but we’re already using RabbitMQ and after wading through the first half of the colorfully written ØMQ guide I’m still not sure if it will support the routing we need but it does look like we’ll have to pretty much write a broker to do it.
5. We actually have the luxury of knowing which hosts are capable of serving which jobs, so we can do something like have host1 subscribe to #.host1.# and host2 to #.host2.#. Then when we route a classB message, we can give it a key of host1.host2 to indicate which backends are acceptable for service. This simplifies the routing rules but still doesn’t  overcome the problem described.